# Como capitalizar la primera letra de cada palabra en POWER-AUTOMATE O SHAREPOINT?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

Hice un PowerAutomate que se conecta a un Forms y las respuestas de ese Forms las paso a un Sharepoint, necesito ponerle a ese Sharepoint o al PowerAutomate que cuando obtenga las respuestas, las pase con la primera letra de cada palabra en mayuscula.
Por ejemplo si en el Forms dice carlos, que se ponga Carlos, si dice jose martin, que se ponga Jose Martin, etc.